# Hosting geoprocessing tool on GeoServer

Tags: geoserver, geoprocessing-service, wps

Like ArcGIS Server, is there a way to host, geoprocessing tools onto Geoserver?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The way to do this would be using the [Web Processing Service (WPS)](https://docs.geoserver.org/latest/en/user/services/wps/index.html) extension to GeoServer which has instructions for [Installing the WPS extension](https://docs.geoserver.org/latest/en/user/services/wps/install.html).